# how do I add '/en' or '/fr' after all the base url in laravel 5.8 routes

Tags: laravel, multilingual

I created a project in Laravel 5.8. I just started working on adding multiple languages in my website. How do I make it so if I click on the language button to choose french the website will load every page as /fr/<rest of the url

Like this

[when selecting english language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nONHu.png)

[when selecting bangla language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7vVw.png)

Comment: did you setup a route parameter for locale for the routes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the button is clicked you should set the desired locale, this can be done using `App::setLocale($locale)`

The documentation of Laravel explains how you could do this, for your exact use case:

[Laravel Configuring The Locale](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#configuring-the-locale)